# what is the reason of decorators not working? (mobx)

Tags: reactjs, decorator, mobx

Decorators don't work without makeAutoObservable(this) function.
Example:
component

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import useStore from 'hooks/useStore'

const Counter = props => {
  const { counterStore } = useStore()
  const { countValue } = counterStore
  console.log(counterStore)
  return (
    <div>
      <button>-</button>
      <p>{countValue} значение</p>
      <button onClick={counterStore.incrementCountValue}>+</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default observer(Counter)
```

store

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx'

export default class CounterStore {
  @observable countValue = 0

  @action incrementCountValue = () => {
    this.countValue = this.countValue + 1
  }
}
```

if to use makeAutoObservable(this) all works good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't MobX v6.x work as expected in React with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268663/why-doesnt-mobx-v6-x-work-as-expected-in-react-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

As of MobX 6 you have to call `makeObservable`/`makeAutoObservable` in the constructor.